# Remover ruído, pontos e traços de imagem

Tags: delphi, processamento-de-imagens, object-pascal

Gostaria de saber como posso processar uma imagem de captcha para remoção de ruídos, traços e pontos. Segue exemplos de como está e como eu gostaria que ficasse.

Imagem Original:

[image: Imagem Original - Captcha]

Imagem Ajustada:

[image: Imagem processada]

Comment: Poderia postar como está o seu código?

Comment: Para a remoção de ruídos recomendo aplicar um filtro de média na sua imagem. Infelizmente aprendi apenas como fazer o algoritmo usando as cores e fico te devendo no delphi.

Comment: Randrade, no momento meu código só esta transformando a imagem em 1 Bit... o processo de limpar ela, referente a essa remoção não tenho nada feito ainda.

Comment: William Okano, tem algum exemplo desse efeito? Posso tentar aplicar

Comment: Você já tem uma resposta que mostra como manipular pixels em Delphi. Assim, é só aplicar um filtro de média na sua imagem (como sugerido pelo colega @WilliamOkano). A ideia básica é iterar sobre os pixels da imagem e calcular a média dos pixels "ao redor" do pixel em análise. O valor obtido (a média dos pixels na "janela" da imagem de entrada) é o valor do pixel para a imagem de saída. Esse tipo de filtro remove bem o tipo de ruído que vc tem, mas pode eliminar detalhes das letras (dependendo do tamanho da janela).

Comment: Mais informações [aqui](http://www.facom.ufu.br/~backes/gsi058/Aula06-FiltragemEspacial.pdf) e [aqui](http://www2.ic.uff.br/~aconci/suavizacao.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue procedimento para realizar a Remoção dos Ruídos, Pontos e alguns traços!

Adicione 1 componente `TImage` e 1 componente `TButton`, no `TImage1` carregue uma imagem **BMP** (para pixel a pixel é o melhor formato, então o procedimento é todo em cima desse formato)

```
procedure frmTeste.btnCorrigirClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  X, Y : Integer;
  vBmpTemp : TBitmap;
begin
  vBmpTemp := TBitmap.Create;
  vBmpTemp.Assign(Image.Picture.Bitmap);
  for X := 0 to Image.Width - 1 do
  begin
    for Y := 0 to Image.Height - 1 do
    begin
      if ((Image.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y] >=  $00000000)  and
          (Image.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y] <=  $00999999)) or
          (Image.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y]  =  $00FEFEFE)  or
          (Image.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y]  =  $00FAFAFA)  or
          (Image.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y]  =  clBlack)    then
      begin
        if ((Image.Canvas.Pixels[X - 1, Y] >=  $00000000)  and
            (Image.Canvas.Pixels[X + 1, Y] <=  $00999999)) then
        begin
          vBmpTemp.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y] := Image.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y];
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  Image.Picture := nil;

  for X := 0 to vBmpTemp.Width - 1 do
  begin
    for Y := 0 to vBmpTemp.Height - 1 do
    begin
      if ((vBmpTemp.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y] >=  $00000000)  and
          (vBmpTemp.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y] <=  $00999999)) or
          (vBmpTemp.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y]  =  $00FEFEFE)  or
          (vBmpTemp.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y]  =  $00FAFAFA)  or
          (vBmpTemp.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y]  =  clBlack)    then
      begin
        if ((vBmpTemp.Canvas.Pixels[X - 1, Y] >=  $00000000)  and
            (vBmpTemp.Canvas.Pixels[X + 1, Y] <=  $00999999)) then
        begin
          Image.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y] := vBmpTemp.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y];
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

O que fiz é bem simples, estou percorrendo toda a imagem pixels a pixels, se encontro uma sequência de cores eu passo ela para o `TImage`.

Cada click no botão vai limpando mais e mais a imagem!
Aguardo o feedback!

Comment: Bom dia! Desculpe pela demora a responder essa postagem, eu estava sem acesso por todo esse tempo. Seu procedimento me atendeu como eu esperava, agora vou fazer mais alguns ajustes para limpar tbm as linhas, permanecendo apenas as letras. Muito obrigado amigo!